# Не удаётся сохранить HashSet коллекцию объектов в XML файл (java)

Tags: java, xml, hashset

Имеются несколько объектов, которые нужно объединить в HashSet коллекцию и сохранить в XML файле и в дальнейшем их от туда извлечь

```
package laba2;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;

import static laba2.XMLworker.*;

public class Laba2 {
    public static void main(String[]args){

        FoodResidus fr1 = new FoodResidus();
        fr1.name=someName1;
        fr1.ID=0;           
        FoodResidus fr2 = new FoodResidus();
        fr2.name=someName2;
        fr2.ID=1; 
        FoodResidus fr3 = new FoodResidus();
        fr3.name=someName3;
        fr3.ID=2; 

        HashSet<FoodResidus> collection = new HashSet<>();
        rubbishBin.add(fr1);
        rubbishBin.add(fr2);
        rubbishBin.add(fr3);



        try {
            saveCollection("some.xml",collection); 
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Для это создал класс с двумя соответсвующими методами

```
package laba2;

import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class XMLworker {
    public static void saveCollection(String path, FoodResidus[] hs)throws JAXBException,IOException {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(FoodResidus[].class);
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        JAXBElement<FoodResidus[]> jaxbElement = new JAXBElement<FoodResidus[]>(new QName("My_XML_Class"), FoodResidus[].class, hs);
        File fileWrite = new File(path);
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileWrite);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        marshaller.marshal(jaxbElement, bw);
    }

    public static HashSet getCollection(String path)throws JAXBException,IOException{
        File fileRead = new File(path);
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileRead);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        HashSet returnedHS = JAXB.unmarshal(br, HashSet.class);
        return returnedHS;
    }
}
```

Смотрю в получившийся файл, а там это:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<My_XML_Class/>
```

Пробовал сохранять каждый объект отдельно, всё выходит корректно и с помощью метода *getCollection()* они прекрасно извлекаются.
Что не так с коллекциями?

Вот класс *FoodResidus*

```js
package laba2;

public class FoodResidus {

    public String name = "someOfFoodresidus";

    public Integer ID=666;

    public boolean fliesAttraction=false;

    public FoodResidus(){}   
    }
}
```

Comment: а класс FoodResidus сериализируемый?

Comment: Я пока не опытен в программировании, но на сколько понимаю - нет. Не сериализуемый

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил
Люди подсказали, что XML не терпит коллекций в роли рутовых объектов
Использовал класс обёртку - *ClassWrapper*

```js
package laba2;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import java.util.HashSet;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ClassWrapper {

    private HashSet<FoodResidus> theCollection;

    public ClassWrapper(){
        theCollection = new HashSet<FoodResidus>();
    }

    public HashSet<FoodResidus> getTheCollection(){
        return theCollection;
    }
    public void setTheCollection(HashSet<FoodResidus> theCollection){
        this.theCollection=theCollection;
    }
}
```

В соответствии с этим немного изменил *XMLworker*

```js
package laba2;

import javax.xml.bind.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.HashSet;

/**
 * Created by danil on 23.02.2017.
 */

public class XMLworker {

    public static void saveCollection(String path, HashSet hs)throws JAXBException,IOException {

        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ClassWrapper.class);
        ClassWrapper cw = new ClassWrapper();
        cw.setTheCollection(hs);
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        File fileWrite = new File(path);
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileWrite);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        marshaller.marshal(cw, bw);
    }

    public static HashSet getCollection(String path)throws JAXBException,IOException{
        File fileRead = new File(path);
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileRead);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        ClassWrapper returnedHS = JAXB.unmarshal(br, ClassWrapper.class);

        return returnedHS.getTheCollection();
    }
}
```

В итоге всё заработало, надеюсь кому-нибудь будет полезно.